# POST method that accept few arguments

Tags: java, rest

Is it possible to write a @POST method that accept few arguments , some objects some primitive ? like this :

```
@POST
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
    @Path("/post")
    public String postMessage(Message msg,Car car,String s,int i) throws Exception{
}
```

if yes - how will the request body looks like ?

Thank you

Comment: did you look at any tutorials for POST?

Comment: Why would you need to use an `int` instead of an `Integer`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible by creating a wrapper container class for input.
e.g.

```
class PostInput{
  private Message message,
  private Car car;
  private String s;
  private int i;

  // getters and setters for properties
}
```

then the signature of method will be

```
public String postMessage(PostInput input)
```

You'd need to form the corresponding json object in the client